# Edit User information by jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, abstracttablemodel

I have a jtable that show a text file contain on own.
Each line in text file is a user record.
I add a edit button to edit each selected row on table.
I use this code, But i don't understand how to do this:

```
public class AllUser extends AbstractTableModel {

UserInformation uiS = new UserInformation();
String[] col = {"ID", "Fname", "Lname", "Gender", "Date"};
List<UserInformation> Udata = new ArrayList<UserInformation>();

public AllUser() {
BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("xxx.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            Udata.add(initializeUserInfos(line));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            }
        }
    }
}

private UserInformation initializeUserInfos(String str) {
    UserInformation Uinit = new UserInformation();
    String[] CellArray = str.split("     ");
    Uinit.setID(CellArray[0]);
    Uinit.setFname(CellArray[1]);
    Uinit.setLname(CellArray[2]);
    Uinit.setGender(CellArray[3]);
    Uinit.setDate(CellArray[4]);
    return Uinit;
}
@Override
public String getColumnName(int colu) {
    return col[colu];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return Udata.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return col.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    UserInformation uinfoS = Udata.get(rowIndex);
    Object value = null;
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            value = uinfoS.getID();
            break;
        case 1:
            value = uinfoS.getFname();
            break;
        case 2:
            value = uinfoS.getLname();
            break;
        case 3:
            value = uinfoS.getGender();
            break;
        case 4:
            value = uinfoS.getDate();
            break;
        default:
            value = "...";
    }
    return value;
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    UserInformation userInfo = new UserInformation();

    switch (columnIndex) {

        case 0:
            userInfo.setID((String) value);
            break;
        case 1:
            userInfo.setFname((String) value);
            break;
        case 2:
            userInfo.setLname((String) value);
            break;
        case 3:
            userInfo.setGender((String) value);
            break;
        case 4:
            userInfo.setDate((String) value);
            break;
    }

}

public Object getSelectedMember(int row){
    UserInformation userInf=new UserInformation();

    Object fname=userInf.getFname();
    Object lname=userInf.getLname();
    Object gender=userInf.getGender();
    Object date=userInf.getDate();
    return // ?

}
}
```

I add This `getSelectedMember(int row)` method to do this, But incorrect!

```
public class UserPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private AllUser userModel;
private JTable uTable;
private JButton editButton;

public UserPage() {
    userModel = new AllUser();
    uTable = new JTable(userModel);
    add(new JScrollPane(uTable), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanels(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(800, 600);
}
public final JPanel buttonPanels() {
    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    editButton=new JButton("Edit");
    editButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonsPanel.add(editButton);
    return buttonsPanel;
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()== editButton){
        int selectedRow=uTable.getSelectedRow();
        if(selectedRow>0){
            editUser(selectedRow);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a user");
        }

    }
}
    public void editUser(int row){
    userModel.getSelectedMember(row);
    new NewUserFrame_Edit().setVisible(true);  
}
}
```

`UserInformation` Class:

```
public class UserInformation {

private String Fname;
private String Lname;
private String ID;
private String Gender;
private String Date;

public String getFname() {
    return Fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.Fname = fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return Lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.Lname = lname;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String i_d) {
    this.ID = i_d;
}

public String getGender() {
    return Gender;
}

public void setGender(String gndr) {
    this.Gender = gndr;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.Date = date;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ID + "     " + Fname + "     "
            + Lname + "     " + Gender + "     " + Date + "\n";
}
}
```

Sorry for long code.

Comment: So, are we supposed to analyze all this code to understand what it's supposed to do, and what it does instead? Provide this information in your question, and ask a specific question. Not just "How to do it" (whatever *it* might be).

Comment: I want to retrive each old line from text file and update it!

Comment: It sould be like this: when user click a row in jtable and clicked a new page should open and then each old data should insert in own textfiled

Comment: And when user update each textfield, and clickd to save, new data should be save.

Comment: do you understand my purpose?

Comment: More or less. Now, do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: Your Question is still not clear . Could not guess what link u want to establish between the JTable and textfield.!!.. how you want them to perform..?

Comment: There are excess component,

Comment: I reduce my code to seem pretty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extra column in table and fill the cell value with `Edit`. Then render the `Edit` cell with appropriate `TableCellRenderer` . Add `MouseListener` to table. Get the `row` and `column` number of the cell clicked on table. If the cell clicked contains value `Edit` , retrieve value at each column of that row and display it in a Panel containing `JTextFields` . Show that Panel using JOptionpane or in a JDialog. Here is the brief code demo for achieving this task:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
class TableRowEdit extends JFrame  
{
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane jsPane;
    private TableModel myModel;
    private JPanel dialogPanel;
    private JTextField tf[];
    private JLabel     lbl[];
    public void prepareAndShowGUI()
    {
        myModel = new MyModel();
        table = new JTable(myModel);
        jsPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new LabelCellRenderer());
        table.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
        getContentPane().add(jsPane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        prepareDialogPanel();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }
    private void prepareDialogPanel()
    {
        dialogPanel = new JPanel();
        int col = table.getColumnCount() - 1;
        dialogPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(col,2));
        tf = new JTextField[col];
        lbl = new JLabel[col];
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            lbl[i] = new JLabel(table.getColumnName(i));
            tf[i] = new JTextField(10);
            dialogPanel.add(lbl[i]);
            dialogPanel.add(tf[i]);
        }
    }
    private void populateTextField(String[] s)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i++ )
        {
            tf[i].setText(s[i]);
        }
    }
    public class LabelCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
    {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Object oValue, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
        {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, oValue,isSelected, hasFocus,row, column);
            String value = (String)oValue;
            JLabel label =(JLabel)c;
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            label.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingUtilities.CENTER);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingUtilities.CENTER);
            label.setText(value);
            return label;
        }
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
        {
            int x = evt.getX();
            int y = evt.getY();
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(x,y));
            int col = table.columnAtPoint(new Point(x,y));
            if (col == 2)
            {
                String arr[] = new String[table.getColumnCount() - 1];
                for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
                {
                    arr[i] = (String)table.getValueAt(row,i);
                }
                populateTextField(arr);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TableRowEdit.this,dialogPanel,"Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                //Write here the code to save changed values to file and update to JTable also.
            }
        }
    }
    private class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel 
    {
        String[] columns = {
                            "Roll No.",
                            "Name",
                            "Action"
                            };
        String[][] inData = {
                                {"1","Huge Jackman","Edit"},
                                {"2","Thomas Andrews","Edit"},
                                {"3","Shiney","Edit"}
                            };
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
        {
            inData[row][col] = (String)value;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {
            return inData[row][col];
        }
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return columns.length;
        }
        @Override 
        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return inData.length;
        }
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col)
        {
            return columns[col];
        }
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                TableRowEdit td = new TableRowEdit();
                td.prepareAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> It sould be like this: when user click a row in jtable and clicked a new page should open and then each old data should insert in own textfiled

1. Add a MouseListener to the table.
2. On a double click you create a JDialog that contains the text fields required to edit the data.
3. You then get the data from the table using the getValueAt(...) method.
4. the user then edits the data in the text fields.
5. When the user clicks the "Save" button on the dialog you get the data from each text field and update the table using the setValueAt(...) method.
6. if you want to save the data in your text file you then need to recreate the enitre file by writing out all the data from the table.

Comment: how to get data from getValueAt(...) method into my JDialog textFields?

Comment: @Sajjad-HiFriend extract the data from the table first and pass it to the dialog